# Как указать точный размер структуры?

Tags: gcc, выравнивание

Чаще всего возникает вопрос о том, как ужать структуру, отменив выравнивание. В исключительных ситуациях нужно, чтобы структура имела определённый размер, но по факту содержала лишь краткий перечень полей. Например, для операций с блочными устройствами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данный вопрос решается использованием атрибута `aligned`. Он действует не только на выравнивание начала структуры, но и на структуру в целом. Например, https://godbolt.org/z/SWgF29